# Графы. Максимальный вес груза

Tags: c++, графы

Имеется транспортная сеть, включающая мосты. При превышении грузоподъемности некоторого моста он разрушается. Определить максимальный вес груза, который может быть транспортирован из пункта А в пункт В без превышения грузоподъемности находящихся на маршруте движения транспорта мостов.

Я нахожу в графе все пути из А в В и вывожу максимальную грузоподъёмность на данном маршруте. Вот функция для этого:

```
void FindPath(int Vertex) { // Поиск всех путей в графе
    if (maxWeight > WeightLimit[Vertex]) {
        lastMaxWeight = maxWeight;
        maxWeight = WeightLimit[Vertex];
    }
    CurrentPath[j] = Vertex; // добавление в путь текущей вершины 
    map.arr[map.mapCount++] = Vertex;  // коррекция множества вершин пути 
    j++;
    if (Vertex == pointB - 1) {
        cout << endl << "Найден путь: ";
        for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) // вывод пути           
            cout << CurrentPath[i] + 1 << " ";
        cout << endl << "Его максимальная грузоподъёмность: " << maxWeight << endl;
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < VertexCount; i++)
            if (!isInMap(i) && matrix[Vertex][i]) // поиск в глубину: выбор продолжения пути без цикла 
                FindPath(i);
    }

    // здесь оказываемся после нахождения очередного пути или в случае попадания в тупик 
    maxWeight = lastMaxWeight;
    map.mapCount--; // исключение из множества вершин пути последней вершины  
    j--;    // возврат в предыдущую вершину 
}
```

Пути находит правильно, но грузоподъёмность выводит неверную.
Например для пути 1-4-5 выводит максимальную грузоподъёмность 27, но на самом деле она 22 (4 мост имеет минимальную грузоподъёмность)
[image]

Вот полный код программы, подскажите, что нужно исправить, чтобы выводило корректную  максимальную грузоподъёмность?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::setw;

#define BridgeCount 10

int matrix[BridgeCount][BridgeCount];  // матрица смежности 
int WeightLimit[BridgeCount];
int VertexCount;   // количество пунктов 
int CurrentPath[BridgeCount]; // текущий путь 
int pointA, pointB, j;
int maxWeight = 0;
int lastMaxWeight = 0;

struct set {
    int arr[BridgeCount];
    int mapCount;
} map; // множество вершин, входящих в путь 


void InputMatrix(int matrix[][BridgeCount]) // ввод матрицы смежности 
{
    int i, j;
    cout << "Введите количество мостов: ";
    cin >> VertexCount;
    for (i = 0; i < VertexCount; i++) {
        cout << "Введите максимальную грузоподъёмность моста " << i + 1 << ": ";
        cin >> WeightLimit[i];
    }
    for (i = 0; i < VertexCount; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < VertexCount; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = 0;
            matrix[j][i] = 0;
        }
    do {
        cout << "Введите связи в виде пары вершин (99-конец): ";
        cin >> i;
        if (i != 99) cin >> j;
        if ((i > 0 && i <= VertexCount) && (j > 0 && j <= VertexCount)) {
            matrix[i - 1][j - 1] = 1;
            matrix[j - 1][i - 1] = 1; // матрица смежности симметрична 
        }
        else if (i != 99) cout << "ОШИБКА ввода!" << endl;
    } while (i != 99);
    cout << "Ввод закончен." << endl;
}

void OutputMatrix(int matrix[][BridgeCount])
{
    int j;
    cout << endl << "  ";
    for (int i = 0; i < VertexCount; i++) cout << setw(2) << i + 1; // номера столбцов матрицы      
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < VertexCount; i++) {
        cout << setw(2) << i + 1; // номера строк матрицы
        for (j = 0; j < VertexCount; j++) cout << setw(2) << matrix[i][j];
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int isInMap(int Vertex) { // Проверка на нахождение во множестве вершин пути
    for (int i = 0; i < map.mapCount; i++)
        if (map.arr[i] == Vertex) return 1;
    return 0;
}

void FindPath(int Vertex) { // Поиск всех путей в графе
    if (maxWeight > WeightLimit[Vertex]) {
        lastMaxWeight = maxWeight;
        maxWeight = WeightLimit[Vertex];
    }
    CurrentPath[j] = Vertex; // добавление в путь текущей вершины 
    map.arr[map.mapCount++] = Vertex;  // коррекция множества вершин пути 
    j++;
    if (Vertex == pointB - 1) {
        cout << endl << "Найден путь: ";
        for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) // вывод пути           
            cout << CurrentPath[i] + 1 << " ";
        cout << endl << "Его максимальная грузоподъёмность: " << maxWeight << endl;
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < VertexCount; i++)
            if (!isInMap(i) && matrix[Vertex][i]) // поиск в глубину: выбор продолжения пути без цикла 
                FindPath(i);
    }

    // здесь оказываемся после нахождения очередного пути или в случае попадания в тупик 
    maxWeight = lastMaxWeight;
    map.mapCount--; // исключение из множества вершин пути последней вершины  
    j--;    // возврат в предыдущую вершину 
}

int main() {
    system("chcp 1251");
    char ch;
    InputMatrix(matrix); // ввод матрицы смежности 
    do {
        OutputMatrix(matrix);
        cout << "Введите исходный пункт A: ";
        cin >> pointA;
        cout << "Введите конечный пункт B: ";
        cin >> pointB;
        for (int i = 0; i < BridgeCount; i++)
            map.arr[i] = 0; // инициализация множества вершин пути 
        maxWeight = WeightLimit[pointA - 1];
        lastMaxWeight = maxWeight;
        j = 0;
        FindPath(pointA - 1); // перечисление всех путей        
        cout << "Путей больше нет!" << endl;
        cout << "Повторить поиск? y/n: ";
        cin >> ch;
    } while (ch != 'n');
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А я правильно вас понял: ваши "мосты" являются вершинами в вашем графе? То есть физически у вас дороги соединяющие мосты попарно что ли?

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл решение проблемы. Теперь, при достижении конечного пункта, я сравниваю грузоподъёмности мостов, которые находятся на пути. Если встречается мост с меньшей грузоподъёмностью, то меняю значение **maxWeight** на неё.

Не очень эффективно, но довольно просто (не знаю, почему сразу до этого не додумался)

```
void FindPath(int Vertex) { // Поиск всех путей в графе
    CurrentPath[j] = Vertex; // добавление в путь текущей вершины 
    map.arr[map.mapCount++] = Vertex;  // коррекция множества вершин пути 
    j++;
    if (Vertex == pointB - 1) {
        cout << endl << "Найден путь: ";
        maxWeight = WeightLimit[CurrentPath[0]];
        for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) { // Вывод пути
            cout << CurrentPath[i] + 1 << " ";
            if (maxWeight > WeightLimit[CurrentPath[i]]) // Расчёт макс. грузоподъёмности
                maxWeight = WeightLimit[CurrentPath[i]];
        }
        cout << endl << "Его максимальная грузоподъёмность: " << maxWeight << endl;
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < BridgeCount; i++)
            if (!isInMap(i) && matrix[Vertex][i]) // поиск в глубину: выбор продолжения пути без цикла 
                FindPath(i);
    }

    // здесь оказываемся после нахождения очередного пути или в случае попадания в тупик 
    map.mapCount--; // исключение из множества вершин пути последней вершины  
    j--;    // возврат в предыдущую вершину 
}
```